# Swift: How to get array element type having available array MirrorType

Tags: ios, swift, generics, reflection

Lets assume I have a `MirrorType` of an Array.

I need to get the type of element of this array type and then create a new element of this type.

e.g.

```
let elementType : Any.Type = some_magic_function(arrayMirrorType)
var arrayElement = some_magic_element_constructor(elementType)
```

I thought it could be possible to cast the `arrayMirrorType.valueType` to `Array<Any>.Type`, e.g.

```
let arrayType = arrayMirrorType.valueType as! Array<Any>.Type
let elementType = arrayType.Generator.Element
```

But casting to `Array<Any>.Type` asserts.

Answer (score 2):

`Array<Any>.Type` is not a subtype of `Array<String>.Type`, so result is `nil` and you get an assertion for a force cast.

What can be done here is iteration through array reflection and query for type of the each it's item.

```
let arrayMirrorType = reflect(array)
```

...

```
for var i = 0; i<arrayMirrorType.count; i++ {
    let elementType = arrayMirrorType[i].1.valueType

    if let intElementType = elementType as? Int.Type {
        let newElement = intElementType(777)
    }
}
```

Comment: Just means that you are getting empty array as an input parameter. I doubt if it's possible to get it's original item type.

Comment: I getting mirror type from the owner object's property where Array<?> is a property type. There are no array instances involved, only types.

Comment: Ok. It should be still possible to test for possible item type by casting `arrayMirrorType.valueType as? Array<TypeCandidate>`. And use constructor afterwards. Looks like patch though.

Comment: The thing is that TypeCandidate is unknown. That's why the type of Element is needed.